# Signal loss in non-reflected light through a tube proportional to square of the length?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Reading a [patent](https://www.google.co.in/patents/US20040114898) I came across the claim: "...a portion of light intersecting the inner metal surface is **not reflected**, resulting in a loss in signal intensity... the signal loss is proportional to the square of the length of the light channel." (0015)

I can see it being proportional to the square of the length if it was making no contact with the tube because of [free-space path loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss), but that wouldn't be applicable inside the tube because the light could not spread spherically. I'm fairly certain it means that some of the light is absorbed, resulting in less intensity. But they provide no justification for why it is proportional to the square of the length. It seems to be like it would be more dependent on the material that the tube is made of as opposed to the length of the tube. Why is the length the main concern?

Answer (score 0):

If the tube was 100% reflective - like the sun tubes in some homes - then there would be no loss.  In this case the tube is absorbing a portion of the light on each reflection, so if a given ray starts with intensity R, and looses a fraction x on each bounce, after one reflection the intensity would be R(1-x); after n bounces it would be R(1-x)^n.

Now consider a large number of rays: if they all entered the tube parallel to the axis, there would be no loss at all.  But if instead the light is randomly directed, as from a diffuse source, each ray will, on average, take n bounces to make it through the tube, where n increases with the length of the tube.

If you know the angular distribution of the rays you could calculate the number of bounces for each angular range; but for a longer, narrower tube the number will be approximately proportional to the tube length.